# Prisma - Connect with different username on each request

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

To achieve multitenancy in my NodeJS application, I'm looking for a way that on each user's request, I can connect it to the appropriate tenant, based on the arguments in the request headers.

For example, if header contains x-tenant: myTenant1
the database that should get established should contain the appropriate username and password while establishing a db connection.

In simple words, Can we establish database connection on each request (with different arguments) using Prisma?

Comment: Hey Muhammad, not sure if that answers your question but there's a really nice article about multi-tenancy with Prisma and NestJS here: https://darioielardi.dev/schema-based-multi-tenancy-with-nestjs-and-prisma

Comment: There's also this library that enables building multi-tenant apps with Prisma: https://github.com/Errorname/prisma-multi-tenant